# javascript object literal notation depth

Tags: javascript, object, literals, notation

I was scouring the internet but I think I didn't do a proper searching job. My question is regarding to Javascript Object Literal Notation. Example bellow.

`var Object = {};
 Object.key = value;`

When trying to go more than one depth level down ie.
`Object.key1.key2 = value;`

I'm getting an undefined error. Obviously I'm doing something wrong. Could someone explain this behaviour to me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

because Object was initialized via `var Object = {};` so you can do `Object.key = value;` which also initialized `Object.key` but `Object.key1` is not initialized yet.

you need to do `Object.key1 = {}` before doing `Object.key1.key2 = value;`

Comment: Right! An object within an object! Thank you very much. That did the trick perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define each object in that depth.

```
var Object = { key1: { key2: value } };
```